# wollen + Passiv

Tags: modal-verb, passive

Zum Beispiel:

> Mein Kreditkonto will aus meinem Giro kompensiert werden.

Was ich damit sagen will: Eine Absicht, das Giro aus dem Kredit zu kompensieren existiert, aber ich habe das Subjekt dieser Absicht nicht spezifiziert (daher die Passive-Form).

Ist das verständlich? Im Allgemeinem finde ich Passivkonstruktionen mit anderen Modalverben, besonders mit "können" oder mit "dürfen". Die Bedeutung dieser Konstruktion scheint mir nicht trivial.

Comment: The meaning of the stated sentence is: *my credit wants to be compensated from my bank account*, which sounds strange. *Die Kreditraten werden vom Girokonto abgebucht* is probably closer to what you are trying to say.

Comment: Das Beispiel war verständlich, auch wenn es wie guidot angemerkt hat etwas abwegig klingt. Aber du hast einige Fehler und Unklarheiten in deiner restlichen Aussage!

Comment: @peterh, bezüglich _Im Allgemeinem finde ich passiv-konstruktionen mit anderen Modalverben, besonders mit "können" oder mit "dürfen"._: Wie findest du sie? Einfacher? Verständlicher?

Comment: @Iris Ich verstehe da, er findet sie, wenn er sie sucht.

Comment: @elena, das könnte sein. Dann würde ich aber sagen: Im Allgemeinem finde ich **P**assiv-**K**onstruktionen **bei** anderen Modalverben, **besonders "können" oder "dürfen"**.

Comment: Ich ahne nur, was du sagen willst, aber der Ahnung nach sollte dein Satz am ehesten (und am nächsten an deinem Original) lauten *Das Kreditkonto* soll *von meinem Girokonto kompensiert werden*. Das könnte man am Bankschalter durchaus sagen.

Comment: Ist das Girokonto gemeint? Dann könnte man allenfalls verkürzen: "Mein Kredit- will aus meinem Girokonto kompensiert werden". Im zweiten Satz ist die Erklärung wohl irrtümlich vertauscht, da ist es plötzlich das Giro(konto?), das aus dem Kredit kompensiert werden soll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz ist verständlich, ist aber etwas ungewöhnlich. "Wollen" + passiv impliziert eine Forderung des Subjektes ("Kreditkonto"). Eines unbelebtes Ding ("Mein Kreditkonto") kann aber nichts fordern.

In einem literarischen Dokument oder etwas veralteter Sprache kann dies aber humorvoll gebraucht werden.

Beispiel von wollen+passiv mit unbelebten Subjekt:

> Mein Hemd will gebügelt werden. (Ich habe aber keine Zeit dafür.)

Falls englisch hilft: "My shirt wants to be ironed".
Bedeutung: Irgend jemand muss mein Hemd bügeln. 
Das Übertragen meiner Pflicht ("mein Hemd bügeln") in eine Forderung des Hemdes ("will gebügelt werden") gibt dem Ganzen etwas humorvolles. Und es impliziert dass jemand anderes als ich das Hemd bügeln kann.

In einem offiziellen Schreiben/Antrag an eine Bank ist das unangebracht.

Vorschlag für offiziellen Brief:

> Mein Kreditkonto soll aus meinem Girokonto bedient/kompensiert werden.
>
> (Ich will das Geld vom Girokonto für das Kreditkonto verwenden)

Comment: Ich behaupte, dass in vielen Fällen solche Passivkonstruktionen so eingebürgert sind, dass humoristisches daran nicht mehr wahrgenommen wird. Mein Kontostand will sich nicht erholen. Das Wetter will einfach nicht besser werden. Der Knochenbruch will nicht verheilen. Als veraltet würde ich derartiges auch nicht wahrnehmen.

Comment: Sorry Leute, aber das ist kein Passiv. Alle Beispiele sind lupenreine Aktiv-Sätze, in denen das Subjekt (das Konto, das Hemd) aktiv etwas tut, nämlich *wollen* oder *sollen*. Ein echter Passivsatz würde so lauten: »Vom Konto wird gewollt, dass es ausgeglichen wird.« »Vom Hemd wird gewollt, dass es gebügelt wird.« »Es wird gewollt, dass das Hemd gebügelt wird.« Das Wesen einer Passiv-Konstruktion ist ja gerade, dass das Agens (der Initiator der Handlung) im Satz fehlt. In allen hier zu lesenden Beispielsätzen ist aber das Subjekt das Agens. *(wird fortgesetzt)*

Comment: *(Fortsetzung):* Der einzige echte Passivsatz ist dieser: »Mein Kreditkonto soll aus meinem Girokonto bedient/kompensiert werden.« Die Aktiv-Form dieses Satz ist nämlich (beispielsweise): »**Ich** soll mein Kreditkonto aus meinem Girokonto bedienen/kompensieren.« Hier ist das Subjekt (»*Ich*«) das Agens, also das Element, das die Handlung durchführt. Dieses Agens fehlt im Passivsatz. Dort schlüpft ein Patiens (nämlich das Konto) in die Rolle des Subjekts.

Comment: Ich habe nie behauptet, dass 'wollen' im passiv steht. 'Bügeln' jedoch ist im Hemd-Beispiel sehr wohl im Passiv -- daher auch meine saloppe Formulierung "wollen + passiv". Vielleicht wäre die Formulierung "aktives Hilfsverb + passives Verb" besser?

Answer (score 2):

Weder der Satz in der Frage, noch die Beispiele in der Antwort von Susanne sind Passiv-Sätze. (Bis auf eine Ausnahme, die ich weiter unten erwähnen werde)

Wenn man Aktiv und Passiv verstehen will, muss man zwischen dem Täter (fachsprachlich dem *Agens*) und dem Erdulder (*Patiens*) einer Handlung unterscheiden:

Das **Agens** (der Täter) ist jenes Element, das selbst eine Handlung ausführt, sie initiiert, oder sonstwie für ihr Zustandekommen verantwortlich ist.

Ein **Patiens** (ein Erdulder) ist ein Element, das auf irgend eine Weise mit einer Handlung zu tun hat, ohne selbst dafür verantwortlich zu sein, dass es die Handlung gibt.

Von diesen semantischen Rollen ist die grammatische Rolle des Subjekts zu unterscheiden:

Das Subjekt eines Satzes ist die höchstrangige Ergänzung eines Prädikats und stimmt mit diesem in Numerus und Person überein. Das Subjekt steht immer im Nominativ.

Im Satz

> Peter schläft.

ist »*Peter*« das Subjekt (steht im Nominativ, stimmt in Numerus und Person mit dem Prädikat »*schläft*« überein und ist die einzige, und somit höchstrangigste Ergänzung des Prädikats. »*Peter*« ist auch das Agens, denn es ist Peter selbst der schläft. Das Schlafen wird von Peter ausgeführt.

Aber in

> Peter wird geweckt.

ist es nicht Peter selbst, der den Weck-Vorgang ausführt. Er ist das Opfer der Aufweckung, und somit das Patiens. Dennoch ist »*Peter*« nach wie vor das Subjekt des Satzes.

**Aktiv - Passiv**

Ein Aktiv-Satz ist nun dadurch gekennzeichnet, dass das Subjekt das Agens ist. Denn hier ist das Subjekt aktiv für die Handlung verantwortlich.

In einem Passiv-Satz ist das Subjekt aber ein Patiens. Es ist nicht selbst der Urheber der Handlung, sondern erduldet oder erleidet die Handlung (daher auch der deutsche Begriff »Leideform« für den Passiv).

In den folgenden Sätzen, die aus der Frage und den Antworten von Susanne stammen, ist das Subjekt selbst für die Handlung verantwortlich oder führt sie selbst aus:

> 1. Mein Kreditkonto will aus meinem Giro kompensiert werden.
> 2. Mein Hemd will gebügelt werden.

Man erkannt das vielleicht besser, wenn man aus diesem Aktivsätzen echte Passivsätze macht:

> 1. Es wird gewollt, dass das Kreditkonto aus meinem Giro kompensiert wird.
> 2. Es wird gewollt, dass mein Hemd gebügelt wird.

Die Konstruktion mit »*Es*« als Subjekt ist notwendig, weil »*wollen*« nicht transitiv ist, und daher streng genommen gar nicht das Prädikat eines echten Passiv-Satzes sein kann. Daher ein anderes Beispiel mit einem transitiven Verb:

> Aktiv: Das Girokonto kompensiert das Kreditkonto.
>   Passiv (ohne Agens): Das Kreditkonto wird kompensiert.
>   Passiv (mit Agens): Das Kreditkonto wird vom Girokonto kompensiert.

---

Der folgende Satz ist hingegen ein echter Passivsatz:

> Mein Kreditkonto soll aus meinem Girokonto bedient/kompensiert werden.

Dieser Satz gibt nicht an, wer die Handlung durchführen wird. Keines der beiden erwähnten Konten tut aktiv etwas. Es gibt hier kein Agens. Um aus diesem Satz einen Aktiv-Satz zu machen, muss also ein handelndes Element herbeigezaubert werden, das vorher nicht da war. Ohne zusätzlichen Kontext hat man hier freie Wahl:

> **Ich** soll mein Kreditkonto aus meinem Girokonto bedienen/kompensieren.
>   **Die Bank** soll mein Kreditkonto aus meinem Girokonto bedienen/kompensieren.

Diese beiden Sätze machen klar, wer hier etwas tut, nämlich das fett hervorgehobene Subjekt, das auch die semantische Rolle des Agens hat.

---

Es gibt noch eine andere Möglichkeit aus einem Passiv-Satz einen Aktiv-Satz zu machen. Dabei wird aber aus einem Patiens ein Agens gemacht, was einen erheblichen Eingriff auf semantischer Ebene bedeutet und somit die Aussage des Satzes gravierend verändert.

Aus

> Mein Kreditkonto soll aus meinem Girokonto bedient/kompensiert werden.

wird dann

> Mein Kreditkonto wird sich aus meinem Girokonto bedienen/kompensieren.

Das alte Subjekt (das Kreditkonto) bleibt auch im neuen Satz das Subjekt, wechselt aber von der Opfer-Rolle (mit dem Konto soll etwas geschehen) in die Rolle des Täters (Das Konto macht selbst etwas). Dass das Kreditkonto in Form des Reflexivpronomens »sich« zusätzlich auch in der Opferrolle auftritt, ist irrelevant, weil »sich« nicht das Subjekt des Satzes ist.